# I am trying to compare two strings but i am having problem

Tags: bash

```
read -p 'username : ' usr_value
read -sp 'password : ' psw_value
echo
a=fghj
if["usr_value" = "$a"]  #I am having problem in this line
   then
     echo "you have correct username" 
   else
     echo "you have incorrect username"
if
```

Comment: Only use Kali tags while referring to problems specific to Kali. Moreover, Kali is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Here I see two problems,

1. Syntax of `if`: You seem to have not followed the proper syntax. It must be like

   ```
   if [ <condition> ] #mind the whitespaces
   ```

   Moreover you need to compare values of `usr_value` and `a` not value of `a` with `usr_value` as a value, i.e. in your code `usr_value` is being treated as a string value not a variable. So, it should be like

   ```
   if [ "$usr_value" = "$a" ]
   ```
2. `if else` should be ended with `fi` but you have used `if` again in the end of `if else` statements.